# Getting error while trying to call a function located in included file with mysqli from a file?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to assign a function for to call site title from database so the function while called at it's assigning page as `functions.php` gives the exact data what I need i.e it outputs the data from database but now getting error while trying to call the same function in `index.php` and I included the function file already but it gives me a common error message as so (please need help) :

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\php-login-new\config\functions.php on line 15

while my `functions.php` file is as :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once('config.php');
function site_title() {
global $mysqli;

$query = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$fetch = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch);
$site_name=$row['site_name'];
echo $site_name;

}

?>
```

while my `config.php` file for mysqli connection is as :

```
<?php

/* Database config */

$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'login'; 

/* End config */

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

?>
```

and here goes the `index.php` file :

```
<?php

include('config/functions.php');

site_title();

?>
```

Comment: Remove the `exit();` in your config file. You're telling it to connect then to get out.

Comment: Plus `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error($mysqli)`

Comment: include and require are not functions! include 'config/functions.php'; is better

Comment: Really I changed those but still no luck with that please..!

Comment: You have `config/functions.php` yet you write "*while my `function.php` file is as*: - is the file called function.php or functions.php? If it's function.php then do `include('config/function.php');`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Sorry for that,writting mistake.just updated the question with exact file name..it's `functions.php` Thanks..!

Comment: I have already the error reporting as this please : `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`

Comment: Thanks for your time I have realized it.! and now posting answer for information base.!

Comment: I tested your code, no problem. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysqli_query%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli%2C+null+given

Comment: What do you mean for information base? The errors are clear enough in comments given.

Comment: @user3791372 what practical difference does that make?

Comment: @MikeB : the `require_once` really cause problems when dealing with mysqli queries or mysqli queries inside the functions nested in alot functions.

Comment: @UmairShah My head...

Answer (score 0):

Really what I was doing wrong is that I was calling the mysqli connection file as `require_once('config/config.php');` 
it worked fine when changed the 
`require_once`
function to 
`include('config/config.php');` 
Thanks to @Fred And @user3791372 for pointing out too.

Comment: You're including/requiring the same file. require throws a fatal error if it can't find it, include doesn't - there's no other difference. Your solution doesn't fit with your original problem of `mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`. If you were using require before and the file couldn't be found you would see a "File Not Found" message, not a mysqli error.

Comment: That's impossible. I don't see how changing the fetching method could cause the error. The error cannot be reproduced by what you've given as an answer or as the question, but from my comments left under the question.

Comment: @MikeB : Yes you are right and Thanks for pointing out the difference.

Comment: @MikeB : Maybe I defined two times that's why it throw an error but just as you said really but it gave too much different error..!

Comment: Really I didn't ask for votes please after all..! you gave negative votes..!

Comment: Yes I did, like I said in my comment above where I got a +1 for it. Somebody agrees with me.